# How to email in Java?

Tags: java, spring, email

Please help with a solution on how to send an email in Java. Contains a message body, subject, etc. A single simple solution will be beneficial. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is to have one method for email purpose and call where ever u need by passing arguments in each method u need.

```
public String sendMail(String message, String subject, String recipientAddress,
        HttpSession session) {

    System.out.println("To:" + recipientAddress);
    System.out.println("Subject:" + subject);
    System.out.println("Message:" + message);

    try {
        SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
        email.setTo(recipientAddress);
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(message);
        mailSender.send(email);
    } catch (MailException e) {
        System.out.println("mail not sent...!" + e);
        return "noEmail";
    }
    return "success";

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will also try to move the message body, subject, etc into the same custom Email object together with your sendMail method. That way I can send minimal arguments and replace parts of the body as needed. This will also have all my body text, subjects etc in one place and can easily find and modify them.

Comment: @Quentinb, Yes sure..!! this will minimize ur code too.